# Gradient effect to left half portion of UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, gradient

Is it possible to make only half portion or half layer of UITableViewCell gradient in iOS?

I am using following code.

```
-(void) addGradient:(UITableViewCell *) _button {
    //  [self removeGradient:_button];
    // Add Border
    CALayer *layer = _cell.layer;
    layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:0.2f].CGColor;

    // Add Shine
    CAGradientLayer *shineLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    shineLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
    shineLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,
                         nil];
    shineLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                            nil];
    [layer addSublayer:shineLayer];

}
```

I am calling this method in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Here i am setting gradient effect to bottom portion of cell completely. But i just need only left half portion of UITableViewCell with the gradient effect. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with setting another frame that is smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another UIView whose frame occupies the half of the UITableViewCell, set the gradient to that view using the snippet you have.

Add the UIView as subview to the UITableViewCell.

```
//Considering cell is the tableviewcell
UIView *leftHalf = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width/2,cell.frame.size.height)];
[self addGradient:leftHalf]; //Assuming the method can take UIView as param.
[cell addSubView: leftHalf];
```